# npm install when deploy Octopus

Tags: npm-install, octopus-deploy

I need to create node_modules in the root app when deploy new version using Octopus
How can I create a run script using a new octopus step? I try:

```
npm install
```

But I get error when execute the script step

> 'The remote script failed with exit code 1'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your build system should be handling that for you. The `node_modules` directory should then be included in your application package, but ideally, this should also be bundled to reduce the number of files that your application is dependant on.

If you do need to run this as part of a deployment, then you would need `NodeJS` and `npm` installed on the server that is executing the deployment step (either the Octopus server itself or a worker instance if using workers).

For more information check out this [blog post](https://octopus.com/blog/deploying-nodejs)